# Multiple xmlhttprequest

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Is it possible with javascript ? or do I need to create two senders ?

because this don't work

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send("textBox="+textBox.value);
xmlhttp.send("textBoxID="+textBox.parentNode.id);
```

Comment: Why don't you send the values together like `xmlhttp.send("textBox="+textBox.value+"&textBoxID="+textBox.parentNode.id);` ?

Comment: Your question suffers from serious issues, please consider revising it to make what you'd like to accomplish clearer, possibly with use cases, expected input/output and a description

Comment: =) ofcourse, Thanks. it works like a charm. post it as answer aswell and I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
xmlhttp.send("textBox="+textBox.value+"&textBoxID="+textBox.parentNode.id);
```

Send multiple params together.

Comment: @Dymond, You are welcome and your name Dymond (Diamond) is Heera in Bengali (Same meaning) :-)